# Method runs without taking user input

Tags: java, methods, input

Hey guys I am writing this program and I have a problem with this method.

```
public int titlesearch()
{
    System.out.println("What is the title of the game you want to search for?");
    String searchkey;
    searchkey =input.nextLine();
    String titlekey=searchkey.toLowerCase();
    for (int i=0;i<gamelist.size();i++)
    {
        String gametitle=gamelist.get(i).getTitle();
        if (gametitle.equals(titlekey) && gamelist.get(i).getSelling()== true)
            {
                System.out.println("Game is found!");
                return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Basically, the problem I have with it is that the first time it runs, it skips taking in user input, and it returns -1, skipping the searchkey=input.nextLine() altogether. However, if I call it a second time, it then works. What is the problem with the method?

```
 Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
 List<gameprofile> gamelist= new Arraylist<>();
```

These are the declarations for the methods above. By the way I already checked, and the entirety of the program runs but this is the only issue I have.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine the way you did it, I see no reason why your input line should be skipped. I tried it and executed it on both Windows and Linux and from command line and within eclipse, it was fine every time.

The only reason I can imagine is, that there is already something in your input buffer, but I wouldn't know why. How do you start your program and in which environment?

PS: A small remark, don't name your classes with a lower-case letter, so it should be `Gameprofile` or even better `GameProfile` instead of `gameprofile`.